# Spring jackson exception with spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I have upgraded spring version from 1.4.3 release to 1.5.3 and started getting below issues on development environment.  In my local it works fine. I cleared my local .m2 directory and it works fine with 1.5.3 but in my QA environment it is failing because of below error

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
```

I was using 1.4.3.RELEASE it was working fine.

```
      logger_name:   org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory   
             message:    Field error in object 'spring.jackson' on field 'null': rejected value [inclusion]; 
    codes [typeMismatch.spring.jackson.null,typeMismatch.null,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [spring.jackson.null,null]; arguments []; default message [null]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature' for property 'null'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: 
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature] for value 'inclusion'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
No enum constant com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.inclusion]
```

Any help what could be wrong?

Comment: what is `inclusion`?

Comment: I don't know. I did not change anything otherthan spring version

Comment: add your `spring.jackson` properties.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe how?  Or you mean in the above question?

Comment: I assume you have some properties or yml file thats trying to be loaded by jackson and throwing an error. would be helpful to see them and add your entire POM